# Vectors and ratios

Tags: vectors

> The point A has position vector <3, 2> and point B has one of <1, 3>. Find the position vector of the point that divides AB in the ratio 4:3.

I have attempted this question by manipulating the position vector values of A and B, but to no avail. Could someone show me how these sorts of questions are approached, as I am unacquainted with these sorts of vector questions?

I would also like to note that I have attempted to work backward from the answer, which is $<13/7, 18/7>$ but I simply do not understand how they obtained those numbers; I was able to come up with the numbers with the ones at hand by do not know what they represent. If A is multiplied by $<4, 3>$, one obtains $18/7$ and if B is multiplied by $<3, 4>$, $13/7$ is obtained, I believe this may be coincidence though.

Comment: I define it as: AB = B-A. Sorry, I will clarify that in the question.

Comment: I do not think I worded my question well, I will try to clarify.

Comment: The points on the line segment between $A$ and $B$ are of the form $(1-\alpha)A + \alpha B$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$. If you want to split this segment into a 4:3 ratio, that means either $\alpha = 4/7$ or $\alpha = 3/7$ depending on how you interpret the ratio. If $\alpha = 4/7$ then this gives us $(1 - \alpha)A + \alpha B = (3/7)\langle 3,2 \rangle + (4/7)\langle 1,3\rangle = \langle 13/7, 18/7 \rangle$ so presumably that's the desired interpretation.

Comment: P.S. If you're wondering where $\alpha = 4/7$ comes from, solve $$\frac{4}{3} = \frac{\alpha}{1 - \alpha}$$

Comment: Thank you, your comment was what I was seeking. I believe my weakness with this question is rooted in my lack of knowledge of ratios– which you have helped me identify. When you mention that it depends on how I interpret the ratio, if I were to use 3/7 as a, would that mean I find the position vector that divides AB in the ratio 3:4 instead of 4:3?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If we take $\alpha = 4/7$ that means we are $4/7$ of the way from $A$ to $B$, i.e. we are closer to $B$ than $A$. If we take $\alpha = 3/7$ then we're closer to $A$ than $B$. Either could reasonably be called a 4:3 or 3:4 ratio, depending on how you want to assign the 3 and the 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to find a point $C$ on the line segment $AB$ such that $|AC|:|CB|=4:3$.

Equivalently, we want $C$ on $AB$ to be such that $|AC|=4s$ and $|CB|=3s$, for some $s > 0$.

Then 
$$|AC|:|AB|=\frac{|AC|}{|AB|}=\frac{|AC|}{|AC|+|CB|}=\frac{4s}{4s+3s}=\frac{4s}{7s}=\frac{4}{7}=4:7$$
hence we must have
\begin{align*}
\vec{C}
&=\vec{A}+{\small{\frac{4}{7}}}\vec{AB}\\[4pt]
&=\langle{3,2}\rangle+{\small{\frac{4}{7}}}\langle{-2,1}\rangle\\[4pt]
&=\langle{{\small{\frac{13}{7}}},{\small{\frac{18}{7}}}}\rangle\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $C=\left({\large{\frac{13}{7}}},{\large{\frac{18}{7}}}\right)$.